# Will the callback function always executed later than the function after its trigger?

Tags: javascript

In a script like below:

```
loadScriptAsync('test.js', func_a);
func_b();
```

The `loadScriptAsync` implementation:

It uses `js.onload = cb` to invoke the callback.

```
function loadScriptAsync(l, cb, _importance = false, _crossOrigin = false, _async = true) {
  var d = document, s = 'script', w = window;
  function go(){
    var js = d.createElement(s);
    js.onload = cb;
    if (_async)
      js.async = "true";
    if (_importance)
      js.fetchpriority = _importance;
    if (_crossOrigin)
      js.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    js.src = l;
    try{d.head.appendChild(js)}catch(e){
      document.documentElement.appendChild(js);
    };
  }

  if (w.addEventListener) {
    w.addEventListener("load", go, false);
  } else if (w.attachEvent) {
    w.attachEvent("onload", go); 
  } else { go() }
};
```

The `loadScriptAsync` is simply a insert `<script>` to `<head>` implementation and call the callback (as its second parameter, in this case `func_a`)

Is the `func_a` ALWAYS executed after `func_b()` is executed?

For instance, if the code is loaded very fast(like from localhost) and/or the `func_b` takes a very long time to execute.

Just wondering, how JS works internally.

Comment: func_b() will always be executed before the func_a() unless `loadScriptAsync`  contains logic to execute func_a synchroniously

Comment: In other words, "It depends on how `loadScriptAsync` is written." (Andrei's comment is a tautology: "It always executes later unless it executes earlier.")

Comment: Can you add the code for `loadScriptAsync`? Depending on the code, `func_b();` will either always run before or always after `func_a`. There is no way that a slow or fast network connection could change the order of execution for this example.

Comment: Depends on how exactly `loadScriptAsync` does "*call the callback*", so you'll need to show us its implementation. If it's actually asynchronous, as the name suggests, then yes it will call `func_b()` right away after the script has started loading, and will execute the script not before the current execution of code has finished.

Comment: @ThomasSablik It's possible that the order can vary from call to call. `function loadScriptAsync(name, callback) { if (cache.contains(name)) callback(); else cache.load(name).then(callback); }` will call `func_a()` early if the file is already cached, but late if it is not.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's right. I didn't consider conditional behavior. The description suggest a very simple implementation.

Comment: Given the supplies loadScriptAsync code, isn't the answer simply "no, unless `!w.addEventListener && !w.attachEvent`"? Client JavaScript is single-threaded and queued async processes aren't touched until the current process completes/yields.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes, because the callback is tied to a JS file getting downloaded, parsed, and loaded into page execution context in response to a new script element getting added to the DOM. While that happens, your `loadScriptAsync` will have already returned and `func_b` will have triggered. Even if the .js file that's being loaded is the smallest possible, browser-level pre-cached file, the current JS synchronous code path gets to finish before that onload event is handled.

(And note that the code you're showing *is* entirely synchronous code, even if it ends up *triggering* an event asynchronously, as a consequence of those synchronously executed instructions)